# XSL left-right justification with Padding

Tags: java, xslt, jaxp

Is there any standard template in XSLT 1.0 available which does justification and pad the field to max length?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately XSLT does not comes with the padding function, the good part is that is very simple to do so as pointed by this blog post: http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/padding.html

(Web archive version: http://web.archive.org/web/20171225234313/http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/padding.html )

For example if you want to right pad a 10 spaces string you can do:

```
<xsl:value-of 
 select="substring(concat($string, '          '), 1, 10))"/>
```

if you need a left pad you can change the order of the concat parameters as following:

```
<xsl:value-of 
 select="substring(concat('          ', $string), 1, 10))"/>
```

Notice that the string with spaces should contain the same amount of chars as your padding is needing, so if you want a 10 pad, you will need a 10 spaces string.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to XSLT. We won't want to literally put the blank strings ( due to maintainability and readability issues). Can you suggest a template where I can pass "max-String" length and the alignment-type to the template?

Comment: The link you provided does that as well! Thanks.

Comment: To left pad should be: `<xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('          ', $string), (1+string-length($string)), (10+string-length($string)))"/>`

Comment: To left pad, `<xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('        ', $string), string-length($string)+1)" />` seems easier ;)

Answer (score -1):

If the goal is to add spaces either to the right or to the left

```
  <xsl:text>&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;</xsl:text>
```