# How to use an XML element in an XML function

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I know that generating fixed width text from XMl is a common need. And I know this question has been asked before, but every answer I've found is unclear to me due to my lack of understand of XSLT functions.

I have several examples of using an XSLT function to pad a string to a particular width. But none of the examples I'f found are very clear on how to use these functions.

I need to take the contents of an XML element, and pad that to a fixed with with spaces. I have found such functions at the below links.

- http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_pad-string-to-length.html
- [XSL left-right justification with Padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808421/xsl-left-right-justification-with-padding)
- http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/padding/str.padding.template.xsl.html

But in each example they pass in a string, such as "1234 Street". How do I use such functions by passing an element such as `<Address>1234 Street</Address>`

Comment: I am afraid your question is not clear. `1234 Street` is a string, not an element. `<StreetAddress>1234 Street</StreetAddress>` is an element - and you would use `<xsl:value-of select="StreetAddress"/>` to get the element's text value and pass it to a string function.

Comment: My question is if i just put, <xsl:value-of select="StreetAddress"/> in the function call where the examples show placing something like "1234 Street"?

Comment: A practical example would be useful, but I believe the answer is yes. Note also that an implicit conversion can take place, so that `string-function(StreetAddress)` ends up being the same thing as `string-function("1234 Street")`. This is probably the more frequent form of use you will see.

Comment: I tried to include the element tags in my question, but i don't know how to make them appear.

Comment: Use the *code sample* button `{}`to format them.

Comment: Thank you, i will try that when i have a chance.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: in the source of this question he correctly wrote `<Address>1234 Street</Address>`, but the OP did not use back-quotes around it, so the XML was ignored. I fixed that, now his question seems to make a bit more sense (though the term "XML functions" I find still unclear, because there is no such thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael already explained, any argument is string-normalized if a function expects a string. If you take your first example from FunctX then you can do the following;

#### Input XML

```
<root>
    <address>1234 Street</address>
<root>
```

#### XSLT

In the below examples I assume you have copied the code from FunctX and bound it to a namespace (I use the `funtcx` prefix).

One way to do it (`.` refers to the context node):

```
<xsl:template match="address">
    <!-- we are now inside address element -->
    <xsl:value-of select="functx:pad-string-to-length(., ' ', 20)
</xsl:template>
```

Other way to do it:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <!-- we are now inside root element -->
    <!-- note, this will process ALL children under "root" that match "address" -->
    <xsl:value-of select="functx:pad-string-to-length(address, ' ', 20)
</xsl:template>
```

Basically: just use any XPath expression that selects the element you want to be passed on to the function should do it. The function has its argument defined as `xs:string`, which will require the processor to get the *value of* of the element before it passes it on to the function.

You do not need to change the function body in any way, you can just use them as-is.