# XML to Fixed width text file formatted details

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report>
  <table1>
    <Detail_Collection>
      <Detail>
        <ReceiptNo>RN12345678</ReceiptNo>
        <ReceiptDate>1980/11/11</ReceiptDate>
        <LastName>Dela Cruz</LastName>
        <FirstName>Juan</FirstName>
        <PurchaseDetails>
          <Item>Wood</Item>
          <Price>25.65</Price>
          <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        </PurchaseDetails>
        <PurchaseDetails>
          <Item>Axe</Item>
          <Price>50.56</Price>
          <Quantity>5</Quantity>
        </PurchaseDetails>
      </Detail>
    </Detail_Collection>
  </table1>
</Report>
```

and I need to convert it to a flat text file using XSLT 1.0

I found this nice solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:variable name="some_spaces" select="'                                                                  '" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Detail_Collection/Detail" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Detail_Collection/Detail">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="format" select="SSN">
            <xsl:with-param name="width" select="number(9-1)"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="format_date" select="DOB">
            <xsl:with-param name="width" select="number(17-10)"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="format" select="LastName">
            <xsl:with-param name="width" select="number(33-18)"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="format" select="FirstName">
            <xsl:with-param name="width" select="number(46-34)"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="format_date" select="Date">
            <xsl:with-param name="width" select="number(54-47)"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="format" select="Time">
            <xsl:with-param name="width" select="number(62-55)"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="format" select="CurrentStreetAddress1">
            <xsl:with-param name="width" select="number(90-63)"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="format" select="CurrentCity">
            <xsl:with-param name="width" select="number(115-91)"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="format" select="CurrentState">
            <xsl:with-param name="width" select="number(131-116)"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template  match="node()" mode ="format">
        <xsl:param name="width" />
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(text(),$some_spaces ), 1, $width+1)"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template  match="node()" mode="format_date">
        <xsl:param name="width" />
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(translate(text(),'/',''),$some_spaces ), 1, $width+1)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the problem is that I have to format every detail according to its data type like below

> **Alphanumeric** - should be 30 characters right filled with spaces
>
> **Numeric (Unsigned)** - should be 15 characters left filled with zeroes
>   e.g. 000000000012345
>
> **Numeric (signed)** - should be 15 characters left filled with zeroes and
>   if negative should denote    'N' e.g. N00000000012345

From my XML file  the output should be:

```
RN12345678                   19801111Dela Cruz                    Juan               Wood               000000000002565000000000000002
RN12345678                   19801111Dela Cruz                    Juan               Axe                000000000005056000000000000005
```

and for example the prices are negative then

```
RN12345678                   19801111Dela Cruz                    Juan               Wood               N00000000002565000000000000002
RN12345678                   19801111Dela Cruz                    Juan               Axe                N00000000005056000000000000005
```

and by the way i have some fields that have 300 characters (like a filler) so i dont know if I need to put 300+ spaces in the variable some_spaces

Dates should be 8 characters YYYYMMDD.

I have a template which im using but not sure how to put the 'N' for the negative ones and how to format the dates according to the requirement.

Here is the template:

```
<xsl:template name="prepend-pad">
    <!-- recursive template to right justify and prepend the value with whatever padChar is passed in   -->
    <xsl:param name="padChar" />
    <xsl:param name="padVar" />
    <xsl:param name="length" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length($padVar) &lt; $length">
        <xsl:call-template name="prepend-pad">
          <xsl:with-param name="padChar" select="$padChar"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="padVar" select="concat($padChar,$padVar)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="length" select="$length"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($padVar,string-length($padVar) - $length + 1)" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

Thanks

Comment: XSL version could be important here, e.g. access to [castable as](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/10/01/tr.html)

Comment: Could you post the expected result of your example? The XSLT does not match your XML, so it's unclear which details you want to output. -- Also, you have no format specified for dates.

Comment: Regarding the padding, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808421/xsl-left-right-justification-with-padding

Comment: Hi Michael, edited my post to include the expected result, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:variable name="spaces" select="'                              '"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Report/table1/Detail_Collection/Detail/PurchaseDetails">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../ReceiptNo"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../ReceiptDate"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../LastName"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../FirstName"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Item"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="format-number">
            <xsl:with-param name="number" select="100 * Price"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="format-number">
            <xsl:with-param name="number" select="Quantity"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>     
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ReceiptNo | LastName | FirstName | Item">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(., $spaces), 1, 30)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ReceiptDate">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '/', '')"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="format-number">
    <xsl:param name="number" select="0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$number >= 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($number, '000000000000000')"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(-$number, 'N00000000000000')"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

I am afraid I did not understand this part:

> and by the way i have some fields that have 300 characters (like a
>   filler) so i dont know if I need to put 300+ spaces in the variable
>   some_spaces

---

### Edit:

To insert 300 spaces in the resulting line, I suggest you use simply:

```
<xsl:text>  (300 spaces here)  </xsl:text>
```

It's possible to use a named template to generate any amount of spaces dynamically but since you need a constant number, I can't see any advantage to it.

> And regarding the date it will be given to me as MM/dd/yyyy and i need
>   to format it as yyyyMMdd, sorry for the wrong sample data I provided.

If so, change the template matching the date field to:

```
<xsl:template match="ReceiptDate">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(., 7, 4), substring(., 1, 2), substring(., 4, 2))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, what I mean by that is that my file have a field which is 300 characters and should be filled by blanks, its like a reserved field and its somewhere before the end of the line. And regarding the date it will be given to me as MM/dd/yyyy and i need to format it as yyyyMMdd, sorry for the wrong sample data I provided.

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don't follow. Do you mean you need to add 300 spaces to each line **of the output** (regardless of the input)? --- BTW, which processor are you using? You may be helped by some extension functions here, if your processor supports them.

Comment: yes something like that, its like a reserved field, i am just using  VS2013.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, your XSL has very little to do with the XML you provided. 
So, working from the vague requirements for a flat text file and formatting the data with padding I made some guesses and came up with the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:variable name="some_spaces" select="'                                                                  '" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Detail_Collection/Detail" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Detail_Collection/Detail">
        <xsl:for-each select="PurchaseDetails">
            <xsl:call-template name="format">
                <xsl:with-param name="textnode" select="../LastName"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="width" select="number(33-18)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="type" select="string('A')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="format">
                <xsl:with-param name="textnode" select="../FirstName"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="width" select="number(46-34)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="type" select="string('A')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="format">
                <xsl:with-param name="textnode" select="../ReceiptDate"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="width" select="number(54-45)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="type" select="string('A')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="format">
                <xsl:with-param name="textnode" select="Item"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="width" select="number(54-45)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="type" select="string('A')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="format">
                <xsl:with-param name="textnode" select="Quantity"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="width" select="number(54-45)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="type" select="string('N')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:call-template name="format">
                <xsl:with-param name="textnode" select="Price"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="width" select="number(54-45)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="type" select="string('N')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="format">
        <xsl:param name="width"/>
        <xsl:param name="textnode"/>
        <xsl:param name="type"/>
        <xsl:variable name="leader_padding">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$type='N' or $type='S'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="translate($some_spaces,' ','0')"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$some_spaces"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="bigstring" select="concat($leader_padding,$textnode)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="truncatedstring" select="substring($bigstring,string-length($bigstring)-$width)"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$type='A'">
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$type='N' or ($type='S' and number($textnode >= 0))">
                <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- type must be S and value must be negative -->
                <xsl:text>N</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:value-of select="$truncatedstring"/>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which when run against your input xml file produces:

```
    Dela Cruz,          Juan, 1980/11/11,       Wood,0000000000200000025.65
    Dela Cruz,          Juan, 1980/11/11,        Axe,0000000000500000050.56
```

There are two lines here because the input format isn't really flat. So I opted to go with one line per purchased item.