# Is there any XPath expression for String Padding in wso2 ESB?

Tags: xpath, wso2, xquery, xpath-2.0, wso2-esb

I have enabled XPath 2.0 configuration `synapse.xpath.dom.failover.enabled=true` in `synapse.properties` but still unable to get string padding done. Is there any expression to achieve it?

Edit :

The length of a particular string needs to be 10 chars, if it is lesser than it, we have to pad it with the special character '%'.

Eg., Input = '**WSO2**', after padding it should be '**WSO2%%%%%%**'

Thanks in advance

Comment: What was the xpath you tried? what do you mean *exactly* by string padding here? (sample string input and the corresponding expected output would be useful)

Comment: Hi, added the sample request and expected string after padding. I tried fn:string-pad(), but it isn't working in wso2.

Comment: There is no fn:string-pad() function defined in any version of XPath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved using XPath 1.0 like so, assuming that `"WSO2"` will be replaced by dynamic input string in the actual implementation :

```
substring(concat('WSO2', '%%%%%%%%%%'), 1, 10)
```

The above XPath basically works by concatenating string of 10 specific for-padding characters to the original input string, and then substring the result to get only the first 10 characters. Found this trick in the following XSL question : [XSL left-right justification with Padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808421/xsl-left-right-justification-with-padding)

To put this in a more generic formula :

```
substring(concat('input_string', '%%%%....'), 1, n)
```

- `input_string` : string to which padding operation will applied
- `%` : character used for padding, repeated `n` times
- `n` : fixed number of characters expected in the output string

Answer (score 4):

The solution from @har07 is fine if you have a reasonable upper bound on the value of n, but if you don't, you can create a string containing '%' repeated $n times using

```
XPath 3.0: string-join((1 to $n)!"%")

XPath 2.0: string-join(for $x in 1 to $n return "%", "")
```

Comment: Hi Michael, Could you please explain the 2nd xpath above, please.

Comment: `1 to $n` produces a sequence of numbers. `for $x in 1 to $n return "%"` produces a sequence of $n strings each of which is the string "%". string-join() joins a sequence of strings into a single string, with the second argument optionally providing a separator.

Comment: 1. How do I add characters *before* the result? I now have `concat(string-join((1 to (10 - string-length('WSO2')))!\"0\"), 'WSO2')`. 2. Is there any chance to replace the redundant occurence of `'WSO2'`? In my case WSO2 is a longer expression (`tokenize(xr:Referenced_purchase_order_line_reference/text(), '[.]')[2]`).

Comment: Please don't add a new supplementary question as a comment on an existing answer, especially one that's five years old. Ask a new question; reference this question if the reference adds value.